# React-select: isClearable does not work if onChange is used

Tags: onchange, react-select

Instead of clearing the options, the dropdown toggles when clicking on the X icon from `isClearable`. If I don't have an `onChange` prop, it clears.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
onChange={(value) => { setFilterParams({ ...filterParams, group: value })}
```

not

```
onChange={(value) => {setFilterParams({ ...filterParams, group: value.id })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if value is not empty.

```
const [filterStatus, setFilterStatus] = useState("");
const paymentStatus = [
  { value: "pending", label: "Pending" },
  { value: "completed", label: "Completed" },
  { value: "refunded", label: "Refunded" },
  { value: "failed", label: "Failed" },
];

<Select
  className="form-control"
  classNamePrefix="select"
  defaultValue={filterStatus}
  isClearable
  isSearchable
  name="filterStatus"
  options={paymentStatus}
  onChange={(options) =>
    !options ? setFilterStatus("") : setFilterStatus(options.value)
  }
/>;
```